# BFS issue, trying to find "children", my counter in my method seem to be wrong

Tags: python, methods, counter, breadth-first-search

So my code is currently looking like this:

```
def hamta():
    ordlista=[]
    fil=open("labb9text.txt")
    ordlista=[]
    for line in fil.readlines():
        ordlista.append(line.strip())
    return ordlista

def setlista():
    ordlista=hamta()
    setlista=set()
    for a in ordlista:
        if a not in setlista:
            setlista.add(a)
    return setlista

def hittabarn(parent):
    mangd=setlista() 
    children=[]
    lparent=list(parent)
    mangd.remove(parent)
    for word in mangd:
        letters=list(word)
        count=0
        i=0
        for a in letters:
            if a==lparent[i]:
                count+=1
                i+=1
            else:
                i+=1
            if count>=2:
                children.append(word)
            if i==2:
                break
        return children
```

The file labb9text.txt is full of words containing three letters, such as fan, man, ulk (swedish words simply). In hamta I just wanna get like a list full of these words, in setlista I dont want any duplicates and I want them to inserted in random order. When it comes to Hittabarn I want it to search through my "setlista" and find "children".

An example is if I use the word "fan" as parameter in the hittabarn-method, then I want it to find words like man, kan, lan (I've switched only the first letter here, but I could just as well have found fsn if that was in my list). Children is with other words the same word but one letter is swapped, doesnt matter where in the word. My hamta() and setlista() is working as far as I can see, but I cant make my hittabarn work, any ideas of where it goes wrong?

Comment: you could feed an interator to set like so: `set([1,1,2,3,4,4])` to get rid of duplicates

Comment: use `for i,a in enumerate(letters):` no need for counter variable

Comment: I tried to remove the counter and just use that for-loop, but I get an error-message (need more than 1 value to unpack)

Comment: forgot the `enumerate`?

Comment: I did add the enumerate now, since the code didnt work before, I cant really tell if it was "good", but I gotta say its looking better at least (even tho its not working yet), gotta read some on the enumerate and see what it does

Answer (score 1):

maybe difflib could help

```
import difflib
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "fan", "fai").ratio()
0.6666666666666666

difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "fan", "fin").ratio()
0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: That thing looks pretty smart, can you use a set() inside that sequencematcher?

Comment: Its solved now, thanks a lot for helping out :D I need a bit of help with another method, gonna post that in another thread if you got time :)